# Invalid property value when using antialiased and grayscale in Mozilla

Tags: css, firefox, browser, font-face

Font smoothing not working in Mozilla (Version 60.0.1 (64-bit)). I added code in my CSS

```
body,html{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

I am getting `Invalid property value` in Mozila.

[image]

It is displaying in Chrome

[image]

Any idea why it's not working?
Would you help me out in this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson, I checked on Windows 10 also checked in Mac book. Today I just updated my browser

Comment: I added a post with my best guess as to the cause of your issue. Possibly you're on an older version of Firefox on your Macbook (pre-25).

Answer (score 1):

The most likely case is that you are using a non-Mac OS X/macOS operating system to run Firefox.

The [MDN web docs entry on `font-smooth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth) specify that:

> Firefox implements a similar property, but with different values: -moz-osx-font-smoothing. It only works on Mac OS X/macOS.

From what I can tell, subpixel-rendering is enabled by default in most web browsers instead of antialiased fonts. [This Usability Post article](http://usabilitypost.com/2012/11/05/stop-fixing-font-smoothing/) explains why this is still an enabled feature in Mac OS X/macOS browsers:

> Subpixel rendering gives us optimal font clarity for your typical dark text on light background. However, on Mac OS X, when this is reversed and you set light text on a dark background, you get a fairly ugly effect where the text becomes overly bold, spilling out of its lines. Switching away from subpixel rendering to antialiasing for light text on dark backgrounds makes it look lighter, countering the bolding effect.

Edit: Also note that the `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;` property only applies to Mac OS X/macOS Firefox 25+. The bug report can be found on [Bugzilla's Bug 857142](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=857142).

Comment: I am using Windows 10, I downloaded the latest firefox from google and  I updated my Firefox from Version 60.0.1 (64-bit) to Version 61.0b (32-bit). but the same issue I am getting it. I know MDN web docs link. Though present in early (2002) drafts of CSS3 Fonts, font-smooth was removed and this specification is not on the standards track.